# Build recursive array with multi level elements

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I need to build multi nested array with recursive `parent => child` structure. This is structure of my base array from database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [alias] => 1_$6MEORB741t1Gx9VlkUbg_0
            [title] => 1_$6MEORB741t1Gx9VlkUbg_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [alias] => 2_49QaOoUw77f1z2I45SyzolKFHtAr_0
            [title] => 2_49QaOoUw77f1z2I45SyzolKFHtAr_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [alias] => 3_PReQ%9EKu--0mTzQX@ZR_pFdq3_0
            [title] => 3_PReQ%9EKu--0mTzQX@ZR_pFdq3_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [alias] => 6_%#e1ho_9fl6#aK$/E$HE6_0
            [title] => 6_%#e1ho_9fl6#aK$/E$HE6_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [alias] => 41_6k5-f4FGy$LT+B21MD#d1qh_0
            [title] => 41_6k5-f4FGy$LT+B21MD#d1qh_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [alias] => 44_kOL/-FYVMx4Od+kDx*7_0
            [title] => 44_kOL/-FYVMx4Od+kDx*7_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [alias] => 46_kh53wZMheD5cK%Kqb$oyEwBA5N%s8JI_0
            [title] => 46_kh53wZMheD5cK%Kqb$oyEwBA5N%s8JI_0
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [alias] => 31_6sOlnp@MncryS0-Q6Syh#%+NkUzywrC_1
            [title] => 31_6sOlnp@MncryS0-Q6Syh#%+NkUzywrC_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [alias] => 32__hH@L#HUL6uB+65zKsIa0XxA+lA4s/R_1
            [title] => 32__hH@L#HUL6uB+65zKsIa0XxA+lA4s/R_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [alias] => 33_Anq2U@2R1zVqi4qHD1kVePol_1
            [title] => 33_Anq2U@2R1zVqi4qHD1kVePol_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 34
            [alias] => 34_xwffzuToahNDaiOgFPc#l-lKvE19VJ#_1
            [title] => 34_xwffzuToahNDaiOgFPc#l-lKvE19VJ#_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [alias] => 35_+3uIEXWM8PQxDR+y*+*pfh*8eJvaHi_1
            [title] => 35_+3uIEXWM8PQxDR+y*+*pfh*8eJvaHi_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 36
            [alias] => 36_SeLju-iXc@8YqqxhUysQ_1
            [title] => 36_SeLju-iXc@8YqqxhUysQ_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 37
            [alias] => 37_NP8uJC$oiFMr70Hb9Q_1
            [title] => 37_NP8uJC$oiFMr70Hb9Q_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [alias] => 38_roIR1kTFM*HO5I2YfIXco_1
            [title] => 38_roIR1kTFM*HO5I2YfIXco_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 39
            [alias] => 39_8@p7WoRatc2I4k_Fc9iiAJZspgz_1
            [title] => 39_8@p7WoRatc2I4k_Fc9iiAJZspgz_1
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [alias] => 8_UmlPj$b0PUPE_IjL4Yo+*S_2
            [title] => 8_UmlPj$b0PUPE_IjL4Yo+*S_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [alias] => 9_EjG-LeftUra0V_Hwwk/j/CXhR_2
            [title] => 9_EjG-LeftUra0V_Hwwk/j/CXhR_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [alias] => 10_5M71NmD@nfgnzhaI-PnDI-*2sib_2
            [title] => 10_5M71NmD@nfgnzhaI-PnDI-*2sib_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [alias] => 11_Q/x1ORAONjvx/Q#c+sR$XS0_2
            [title] => 11_Q/x1ORAONjvx/Q#c+sR$XS0_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [alias] => 12_uf0VO8aE_7#GRWnYvLnIce9%O8J5M1o_2
            [title] => 12_uf0VO8aE_7#GRWnYvLnIce9%O8J5M1o_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [alias] => 13_LIWs_prfH@O/A$yr_2
            [title] => 13_LIWs_prfH@O/A$yr_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [alias] => 14_3oB%%$4FbPYLgsbiTiQy8fo@j90vT8S_2
            [title] => 14_3oB%%$4FbPYLgsbiTiQy8fo@j90vT8S_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [alias] => 15_18DynIH%bFwo%*nvogdQZ1Bm*rfs_2
            [title] => 15_18DynIH%bFwo%*nvogdQZ1Bm*rfs_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [alias] => 16_AI#kwK4e/AFla-s_6mKKQM_2
            [title] => 16_AI#kwK4e/AFla-s_6mKKQM_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [alias] => 17_Rtf7obmbv-SClvy@l@x*MEtl$A7_2
            [title] => 17_Rtf7obmbv-SClvy@l@x*MEtl$A7_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [alias] => 18_G3tba8ZDbZnSfrfJ3-$BnVdxg_q_2
            [title] => 18_G3tba8ZDbZnSfrfJ3-$BnVdxg_q_2
            [parent] => 2
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [alias] => 23_ig1zkz8w/J@SD2TZ_UYU9_8
            [title] => 23_ig1zkz8w/J@SD2TZ_UYU9_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [alias] => 24_MjCMYvRE+7$kiCLmYj8opHsTqV0_8
            [title] => 24_MjCMYvRE+7$kiCLmYj8opHsTqV0_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [alias] => 25_Jn94#JheMQRg$9h#HD1JN-k%W5_8
            [title] => 25_Jn94#JheMQRg$9h#HD1JN-k%W5_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [alias] => 26_l_+_Q3bGBHF3JUer_8
            [title] => 26_l_+_Q3bGBHF3JUer_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [alias] => 27_/ybSUUr++TLAKm9N8xG8FQCrWW*-_8
            [title] => 27_/ybSUUr++TLAKm9N8xG8FQCrWW*-_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [alias] => 28_EiRh83le0C8Etr5JxVgG4V/0$q_8
            [title] => 28_EiRh83le0C8Etr5JxVgG4V/0$q_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [alias] => 29_Fc-k7Bo8Py8M$_N@oAXZ_8
            [title] => 29_Fc-k7Bo8Py8M$_N@oAXZ_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [id] => 30
            [alias] => 30_6mr1uGtk2BBiyH-r5NgKh90udT1_8
            [title] => 30_6mr1uGtk2BBiyH-r5NgKh90udT1_8
            [parent] => 8
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [alias] => 19_8UhvJLSYjUXERKC@ui_15
            [title] => 19_8UhvJLSYjUXERKC@ui_15
            [parent] => 15
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [alias] => 20_zPSW#YdHV2YpT@#b_15
            [title] => 20_zPSW#YdHV2YpT@#b_15
            [parent] => 15
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [alias] => 21_2-8n54Uk_@3V4pC2rd%0Z4bxYJHzHiDS_15
            [title] => 21_2-8n54Uk_@3V4pC2rd%0Z4bxYJHzHiDS_15
            [parent] => 15
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [alias] => 22_487ALLt8%$KaQHu8_uEQcXd_15
            [title] => 22_487ALLt8%$KaQHu8_uEQcXd_15
            [parent] => 15
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
            [alias] => 42_JILU6%CeT-*oH*VvAExEXfI_41
            [title] => 42_JILU6%CeT-*oH*VvAExEXfI_41
            [parent] => 41
        )

)
```

I am trying to make it with needable structure, but it have only one nested level. And last array elements don't have any `['title']` or `['alias']` anymore, for some reason they are empty.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [alias] => 1_NhTYh1gUeq+aPgITUe@Ue3*_0
            [title] => 1_NhTYh1gUeq+aPgITUe@Ue3*_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [alias] => 2_5bs1UwWeTqE-USEdP27dyl_0
            [title] => 2_5bs1UwWeTqE-USEdP27dyl_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [31] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                            [alias] => 31_@iV2wXID3z$A-@4-whrhqMCWn$_JS37T_1
                            [title] => 31_@iV2wXID3z$A-@4-whrhqMCWn$_JS37T_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [32] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 32
                            [alias] => 32_%lBpA5s-CMr2-_y/0XygzsT1je_1
                            [title] => 32_%lBpA5s-CMr2-_y/0XygzsT1je_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [33] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33
                            [alias] => 33_$8WmYjxwhKmWJPVKr3n-T6lOtJ-%O/T_1
                            [title] => 33_$8WmYjxwhKmWJPVKr3n-T6lOtJ-%O/T_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [34] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 34
                            [alias] => 34_-NrDtGtSTs6QQ%C8D1qQVomYGtrA3KR_1
                            [title] => 34_-NrDtGtSTs6QQ%C8D1qQVomYGtrA3KR_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [35] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [alias] => 35_M-3Z8$RjDnEAX%/d_1
                            [title] => 35_M-3Z8$RjDnEAX%/d_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [36] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 36
                            [alias] => 36_3mG2ZZ8E6/xqafYi@yH/_btGNN_1
                            [title] => 36_3mG2ZZ8E6/xqafYi@yH/_btGNN_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [37] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 37
                            [alias] => 37_TgZPOGOn/q#5z%%uF#-xJxD-%eB9_1
                            [title] => 37_TgZPOGOn/q#5z%%uF#-xJxD-%eB9_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [38] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 38
                            [alias] => 38_aAL3XY073HAF-LOCiCrUX5BK-36_1
                            [title] => 38_aAL3XY073HAF-LOCiCrUX5BK-36_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [39] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39
                            [alias] => 39_V4m14DvYH+CYAujhG$_1
                            [title] => 39_V4m14DvYH+CYAujhG$_1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [alias] => 3_Vf-H5jJqh8BI7_rdyQ4*T+d#3W3_0
            [title] => 3_Vf-H5jJqh8BI7_rdyQ4*T+d#3W3_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [alias] => 8_d%aNC6+UrXC-h-RKMVnyToi5a2q1C_2
                            [title] => 8_d%aNC6+UrXC-h-RKMVnyToi5a2q1C_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [alias] => 9_Lv_VdDX13CR25c9@0r_2
                            [title] => 9_Lv_VdDX13CR25c9@0r_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [alias] => 10_M017XoFg8/R0C1BnPxAG5QFr9_2
                            [title] => 10_M017XoFg8/R0C1BnPxAG5QFr9_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [alias] => 11_c1%#p4oPN03T@-l9jR$Xs%LwT_2
                            [title] => 11_c1%#p4oPN03T@-l9jR$Xs%LwT_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [alias] => 12_N3b3q%#+z_zA4yOz21xQJP+m-%Cf_2
                            [title] => 12_N3b3q%#+z_zA4yOz21xQJP+m-%Cf_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 13
                            [alias] => 13_V0dT%mxNCtvo$vIeKS-LLZ-_2
                            [title] => 13_V0dT%mxNCtvo$vIeKS-LLZ-_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [alias] => 14_#*HZghpHwL446h%EAh4i/V_2
                            [title] => 14_#*HZghpHwL446h%EAh4i/V_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15
                            [alias] => 15_dljC2PL1DwlA89aXMvv+-%@6tOW09-4_2
                            [title] => 15_dljC2PL1DwlA89aXMvv+-%@6tOW09-4_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                            [alias] => 16_AFZQSkFnWVPLT*/Bj_2
                            [title] => 16_AFZQSkFnWVPLT*/Bj_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [alias] => 17_YVoiXtCToZ-rSzr3+ph#_2
                            [title] => 17_YVoiXtCToZ-rSzr3+ph#_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [alias] => 18_2KP2yEro@a/j/C#tvWu%FC9_2
                            [title] => 18_2KP2yEro@a/j/C#tvWu%FC9_2
                            [parent] => 2
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [alias] => 6_b-yfo3qYQy-zuy_8GKDcf68G3P$_0
            [title] => 6_b-yfo3qYQy-zuy_8GKDcf68G3P$_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [alias] => 41_C5eS+rZF#CfaSjZ#k98zNt_0
            [title] => 41_C5eS+rZF#CfaSjZ#k98zNt_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [alias] => 44_i$plAaN1J6L-M*De@j/7P_pjWBmP_0
            [title] => 44_i$plAaN1J6L-M*De@j/7P_pjWBmP_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [alias] => 46_qzfW+xg%T1O9F4K_+%Ef@TT0mO2u_0
            [title] => 46_qzfW+xg%T1O9F4K_+%Ef@TT0mO2u_0
            [parent] => 0
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [alias] => 23_%q3@gkGhD_R2msKavVG_8
                            [title] => 23_%q3@gkGhD_R2msKavVG_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [alias] => 24_ilxGSzJU#%VIdiEaQ_8
                            [title] => 24_ilxGSzJU#%VIdiEaQ_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                            [alias] => 25_NUyuJ/LH*ag4DdKb2Dv9/I2m_8
                            [title] => 25_NUyuJ/LH*ag4DdKb2Dv9/I2m_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 26
                            [alias] => 26_Q7gKTrq#akhlecg9i-UX_8
                            [title] => 26_Q7gKTrq#akhlecg9i-UX_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [27] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 27
                            [alias] => 27_r%dUQ0ceNL8SpjxbnO7U6V%dZIHzN_jx_8
                            [title] => 27_r%dUQ0ceNL8SpjxbnO7U6V%dZIHzN_jx_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [28] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                            [alias] => 28_Hzu9w*5%o#Nk7ZblSB4t$Xp_8
                            [title] => 28_Hzu9w*5%o#Nk7ZblSB4t$Xp_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [29] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 29
                            [alias] => 29_O2EecAUe$tdOQ+/Zbp0SH@x0bHxV_8
                            [title] => 29_O2EecAUe$tdOQ+/Zbp0SH@x0bHxV_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [alias] => 30_plqN4QwSdUJpEe4E-4Pqy4A_8
                            [title] => 30_plqN4QwSdUJpEe4E-4Pqy4A_8
                            [parent] => 8
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [alias] => 19_q1$-DC4agbkN9m2$_15
                            [title] => 19_q1$-DC4agbkN9m2$_15
                            [parent] => 15
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [alias] => 20_lkrWn*RlkV5fJTZdB9J4D/y$S8_15
                            [title] => 20_lkrWn*RlkV5fJTZdB9J4D/y$S8_15
                            [parent] => 15
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [alias] => 21_-zUwInzm*tZ-P0vk3$sg54LLh6Dn_15
                            [title] => 21_-zUwInzm*tZ-P0vk3$sg54LLh6Dn_15
                            [parent] => 15
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [alias] => 22_R6YJQLjqp-lmozYSM4uhGBL4_15
                            [title] => 22_R6YJQLjqp-lmozYSM4uhGBL4_15
                            [parent] => 15
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [42] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 42
                            [alias] => 42_cMScoiEeD1@bwSI$S_41
                            [title] => 42_cMScoiEeD1@bwSI$S_41
                            [parent] => 41
                            [depth] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My code.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['parent'] != 0) {
        $item['depth'] = 1;
        $temp = $item;
        unset($data[$key]);
        $data[$temp['parent']]['child'][$temp['id']] = $temp;
    } else {
        $data[$key]['depth'] = 0;
    }
}
return $data;
```

How fix it and make this array multilevel?